# html5 required validator not working with input type=button

Tags: html, required, required-field

Here is my html code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<input id="q" required />
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

I have used html5 required field validators, it works but with a post back.
so  modified the code as follows to avoid postback

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<input id="q" required />
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Search">
</form>
```

But the required validator doesn't work

Comment: required is only work with submit button

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because the required validator is only called on submit, and the type=button is not a submit. Try this (http://jsfiddle.net/upgradellc/vrTLw/):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input id="q" required />
    <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: How can I use a web font or icon like <i
                                            class="fa fa-fw fa-save"></i> with this?