# Required attribute on inputs in bootstrap is not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation, required

Why is the required attribute on inputs in bootstrap is not working?

```
<input type = "text" id = "thisisatext" class= "form-control" required>
```

Comment: I have several textbox on the webpage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163023/html5-required-validator-not-working-with-input-type-button

Comment: But i don't use submit button, i used <button></button>

Comment: If you want required field working ,it must be a form.First understand clearly between the form and button onClick().My answer explains clearly

Comment: Would you recommend me something that I can use in validations for empty input fields without using forms? :)

Comment: yea :) but i will be needing forms and a submit button. in my case, I'm using  onlick buttons because the ajax in the javascript will going to process the queries on the separate php file. So is there any alternative way to validate empty input fields without using forms?

Answer (score 0):

Use this type,it will work [Validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)

```html
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Cina Saffary" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputTwitter" class="control-label">Twitter</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
      <input type="text" pattern="^([_A-z0-9]){3,}$" maxlength="20" class="form-control" id="inputTwitter" placeholder="1000hz" required>
    </div>
    <span class="help-block with-errors">Up to 20 letters, numbers and underscores</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <input type="password" data-minlength="6" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
      <span class="help-block">Minimum of 6 characters</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Whoops, these don't match" placeholder="Confirm" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
        Boxers
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
        Briefs
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="terms" data-error="Before you wreck yourself" required>
        Check yourself
      </label>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: what if I don't use forms? I used <buttons> on processing data to javascript (ajax) to php that's why i dont use submitting forms.